# how to align a tab at the right in primefaces tabView?

Tags: primefaces, tabs, tabview

I want to place a tab on the right (and leave the other on the left normal position) in the `<p:tabView>`... Like in the showcase site of primefaces (the tab of documentation)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983280/aligning-primefaces-ptabview-to-the-right

Comment: @RachelGallen I saw that question, but I want to align only one tab (or 2) not all of them, so I can't change the css of all tabs like specified there.
PS: there is no style attribute for the `<p:tab>` tag

Comment: @RachelGallen Please delete your edit on my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with the jQuery children selector. If your tabView's id is form:acc, then the following would be correct:

```
var tabs = $( "#form\\:acc ul" ).children();
var selectedChild = tabs.eq(tabs.length - 1); //selects the last tab.
selectedChild.css( "float", "right" );
```

What this does is that it takes the last tab and moves it to the right. However, if you do not want the last tab to move, you can select it's index and your second line would change:

```
var selectedChild = tabs.eq(1); //selects the tab with index 1.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I wanted :)